# Javascript object.create doesn't seem to work if object contains array

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having a problem with Object.Create, when the object contains an array. For example:

```
var Doodah = {
  doo: 0,
  dah: [0,0]
}

var dd1 = Object.create(Doodah);
```

... and later ...

```
var dd2 = Object.create(Doodah);
```

Both dd1 and dd2 seem to reference the same array for 'dah'. Do I need to have an actual constructor?

Comment: The object you pass to `Object.create()` will be the *prototype* for the newly-created object. You use the same object as the prototype for both created objects, so the same inherited property will of course have the same value.

Comment: Object.create()!=Object.Create()

Comment: This isn't just for arrays. Any reference-type (object or array) referenced in the properties will continue to be referenced. `Object.create()` doesn't deep-copy objects.

Comment: _"Do I need to have an actual constructor?"_ Not if you don't plan to mutate `dah`. Assigning a new value to `dd1.dah` will not affect `dd2.dah`. https://jsfiddle.net/bwan6Lb4/

Comment: `function create() { return { doo: 0, dah: [0,0] }` will always return a new deeply nested object instance every time

Comment: A sucky as this idea is there is a way to create a full **deep copy** of another object. `var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));`. While I don't recommend this process it will work.

Comment: @JLRishe -- you should clarify that, because the reference points to the same object. *Altering* the array changes it for both objects.

Comment: @Mark_M Yes, that's why I said "Not if you _don't plan to mutate_ dah."

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now.